# PHP: Speeding up a very large loop

Tags: php, arrays

I've seen this asked before, and maybe this is something I need to pass off to another language (ideally not) but I'm stuck trying to optimize looping through a large array.

I have a (potentially) large 2d array that looks something like this.

```
[
  ['i am a string']
  ['i am also a string']
]
```

And I need to loop through the array and count all instances of words.

Here's the current loop for that.

```
$words = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $text = explode(' ', $row);

    foreach ($text as $word) {
        if (isset($words[$word])) {
            $words[$word]++;
            continue;
        }

        $words[$word] = 1;
    }
}
```

I've tested this with `array_reduce`, `array_map`, converting it to a single (massive) array of words and using `array_count_values` but so far this `foreach` loop is the fastest way to do it.

But I'm really hoping there's a faster way that I have yet to discover.

For reference, I'm going through about 250k words in this instance, but that number goes up by the day.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a database? Could you cache the results instead of calculating it on the fly every time?

Comment: You might want to try [`str_word_count `](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) - could be backed by a C function which is more effective than exploding and looping through the words. But then again this is PHP and it could very well be backed by something truly horrible.

Comment: @samlev, I am, but getting it from the DB takes like half a second, so that's not causing enough of a backup to concern me. After lots of testing, it's this counting logic (and all others I've tried) that cause the script to run for a very long time.

Comment: Thanks @max. Let me give that a shot!

Comment: @max even though your suggestion is useful, why tap in the dark when you can [view the source of the function](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/standard/string.c#5415) and ensure what it's doing? Also, what is the real issue here? How slow is the algorithm? Have you thought of using generators to see if coroutine approach could help?

Comment: @mjh I'm unfamiliar with generators in PHP (use them in JS a lot, but never in PHP) I'm gonna go look at that and see how that can be used. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Scheda - no, I mean calculate it and then save the results in a table so that you don't have to calculate it every time.

Comment: Right, that's what we'll be doing in the next version of our application that we're working on. We'll be using Influx to store this data that we'll be processing constantly. In the meantime, I just need it optimized enough to not time out for the user. If that means I have to go with a cache, so be it, but for now that's not ideal.

Comment: This is a fitting task for parallel execution. Since the algorithm is trivial (get sentences, count words), have you thought about splitting it across processes or even using `ptreads` extension to have all your cores busy?

Comment: @Mjh - I have. Just haven't explored that option yet since it would require me to pester our sysadmin to recompile PHP. That just may be what we have to do though. This dataset won't be getting any smaller.

Comment: @Mjh I don't really know C but `str_word_count ` is basically looping through the chars, until it finds a word boundary and then incrementing the counter? Should still be more efficient than a PHP loop?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that jumps out is your use of `foreach` instead of `count` and a `for` loop. `for` loops with pre-`count`ing are usually much, much faster than `foreach` loops. See [PHPBench.com](http://phpbench.com) for some test results.

Also, you might be better off using a binary tree, rather than an associative array. An associative array with potentially thousands of elements is likely to cause huge memory and performance issues.

Finally, as others have pointed out in comments, cache some of this if possible. That's a huge calculation to perform regularly if you can be sure that at least some of the data doesn't change.

Comment: Any insights on the speed of `str_word_count`?

Comment: @max I'd definitely try it. Probably a little faster, but I have no personal experience benchmarking it to verify that.

Comment: @EdCottrell - Right now this is kind of just a placeholder. We're working on a new version of our statistics application that caches all this data for us, but until this is done we need something that doesn't time out our load balancer so we can display this data to customers. (Growth problems ftw)

Comment: That's an interesting website. I'm running the tests myself (php 5.6.10) and I'm noticing that the [`foreach` loop](http://www.phpbench.com/source/test2/1/) appears to be _faster_ than the [`for` loop](http://www.phpbench.com/source/test2/3/). Maybe PHPbench is testing with an older version of PHP?

Comment: @HPierce hmm, could be.

Comment: Nowadays the inverse seems to be true, judging by the same site's own benchmarks with PHP 8. `foreach` is faster.

Comment: @HashimAziz Could be. I haven’t done any benchmarking in PHP in a while, but I know there have been significant improvements in this area.